# HTML Checkbox - save value as "Yes" / "No" instead of "true" / "false" in database (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, checkbox

I want to save the checkbox value as  "Yes" / "No"  instead of "true" / "false" in database. Am using reactjs to fetching the values and storing in the database.

Please find my below code, that am trying.

```
handleInputChange(e) {
    const target = e.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const item = this.state.item;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    if( name === "should_create" && value === false )
        {
            this.state.item.should_create="No";
        }
    else if( name === "should_create" && value === true )
        {
            this.state.item.should_create=="Yes";

        }
    else
        {
            this.state.item.should_create=="";
        }
            item[name] = value;
            this.setState({ item: item });

    }
```

HTML Check box code :

```
<input name="should_create" checked={this.state.item.should_create==true ? "true":''} type="checkbox" value={ this.state.item.should_create } onChange={ this.handleInputChange } />
```

But, the above code is not working properly. Its storing the default value "true" / "false" only. How can i change it to "Yes" / "No" value ?

I have multiple "Checkbox" component, but i want this "Yes" / "No" options for this only one component. Remaining component should be as default.

Comment: Your approach is entirely wrong. The "Is it checked or not?" state is described **solely** by the presence or absence of the `checked` property **not** the `value`. The `value` is used to distinguish between multiple checkboxes *with the same name* (for things like "Check all that apply" questions). What's more, databases often support boolean fields (which are `true` / `false`) and you shouldn't try to store "Yes" and "No" there instead, that is something to do in the **view** when you render the database as text (note "as text", not as checkboxes!)

Comment: `should_create` will not exist as

Comment: Why you want to use yes/no instead of true/false? What's the need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `==` as an assignment, but it's almost the same as `===` (an expression that returns true or false)

So it's better to create a variable and then just update the state

```
let shouldCreate = ''

if (name === 'should_create') {
  shouldCreate = value ? 'Yes' : 'No'
}

item[name] = value;
this.setState({ item: item });
```

Likely it should help https://codesandbox.io/s/v8v267m23l

Comment: Using `value === true` is total crap. **In a condition the expression always returns a boolean**. To check for true just use `value` and to check for false use `!value`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I just copied expressions from question, I completely agree with you, but this part is not related to the answer and initial problem

Comment: @MarkusZeller anyway, I'll update answer with your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Also no need to make complicated if statements. `shouldCreate = (name === "should_create" && value) ? "Yes" : "No";`

Comment: Sorry for nagging, but why an extra if? This not necessary. `let shouldCreate = (name === "should_create" && value) ? "Yes" : "No";`is enough.

Comment: @MarkusZeller check the original logic. In your case result will be either "yes" or "no", but there is also third possible value `''`

Comment: in any case, it's my personal opinion - I prefer `if` before inline logic in ternary operator